# What is a themed color in Android which is returned by the new Resources.getColor((int id, Resources.Theme theme) method?

Tags: android, resources, themes, getcolor

So `Resources.getColor(int id)` method is now deprecated, and the API doc suggests us use new `Resources.getColor(int id, Resources.Theme theme)` method.

Also I know there is `ContextCompat.getColor(Context context, int id)` method. But this is a simple wrapper which calls `Context.getColor(int id)` or `Resources.getColor(int id)` according to current API level. The `Resources.getColor(int id, Resources.Theme theme)` doc says it returns

> **a themed color** integer associated with a particular resource ID

and the parameter `Resources.Theme theme` is used

> to style the color attributes

Also `Context.getColor()` doc says, it returns

> a color associated with a particular resource ID and **styled for the current theme**.

So I think the real question is **"what is a themed color?"** I've always declared color resources like below which is identical with the [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#color-element).

```
<resources>
    <color name="translucent_red">#80ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

I've never heard of such concept before, and I am not sure which value should I pass for the second parameter in the future.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/38848496/4504191