# What does the "the returned color will be styled for the specified Context's theme" mean?

Tags: android

I recently noticed that a method

```
Context.getResources.getColor(int)
```

is deprecated since API 23.
One should instead use

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

The docs say about it:

> int getColor (Context context,  int id) Returns a color associated
>   with a particular resource ID Starting in M, the returned color will
>   be styled for the specified Context's theme.

But, what does it mean that a color will be styled for a particular theme. Isn't a color color? A constant? Predefined colors are used in themes. So how can it be styled?

Comment: As luck would have it, Alex Lockwood published an article about this a couple of days ago: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs for `Resources` - `int getColor (int id, Resources.Theme theme)`:

> Returns a themed color integer associated with a particular resource ID. If the resource holds a complex ColorStateList, then the default color from the set is returned.

So the resource id can be more than just a simple color, it could point to something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="@color/sample_focused" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="false"
          android:color="@color/sample_disabled_pressed" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          android:color="@color/sample_disabled_not_pressed" />
    <item android:color="@color/sample_default" />
 </selector>
```

in which case the color returned would be `@color/sample_default`.

But if you wanted to use attributes for the colors, something like this

```
    <item android:color="?attr/sample_default_color" />
```

you would need to access the attribute value within the theme in order to completely resolve the color value.

According to [Alex Lockwood's blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html), these resources aren't actually attached to a theme, and if you call the old method with a color state list that uses attributes, an exception will be thrown.  Before Marshmallow, you couldn't use attributes in color state lists due to this limitation.

Comment: Thank you. But is it not so that in state list selectors we cannot use attributes, just fixed colors. But, you might have a point there. I will wait a little bit longer if something else comes along.

Comment: You can indeed use attributes for the color values.

Comment: It was my experience, that you can not use attributes for colors values in state list selectors. I tried it. On older versions and support library. So I guess this is something new in newer apis. Thumb up.

Comment: You are correct.  I thought you could use attributes in earlier releases, but turns out that this is new for Marshmallow.